# How to run java applets on Mac OS?

Tags: java, applet

> Error: java.applet has been deprecated and marked for removal

Appletviewer is also not supported on Mac

Applets were deprecated in JDK 9 and aren’t supported by browsers like chrome, safari or Firefox anymore

Comment: Use a browser version from 2010.

Comment: Applet is a AWT Panel so in certain circumstances you can set one up inside your own container if you call the correct sequence of Applet lifecycle calls (init etc) and if your container handles the appropriate AppletStub callbacks. Not recommended.

Comment: please do not tell stack overflow users that `code needs to be run urgently` everyone at stack overflow answers questions for free on our spare time. If you need urgent answers you should buy a support contract with the specific vendor. Also telling that your question is urgent is sort of telling that your question is more important than everyone elses question. Which it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

[*Java Applet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet) technology is at end-of-life, having proven too difficult to securely integrate with various web browsers.

Read the 2020-05 white paper by Oracle, [*Java Client Roadmap Update*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdatev2020may-6548840.pdf).

Long story short:

> Applet support ended in March 2019
>
> …
>
> Components required to run Applets on non-Windows platforms are being removed starting July 2020

You can fairly easily rewrite your Java Applet to be a [Java Swing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)) desktop app. Swing continues to be a required part of every Java implementation. Though not actively developed, Swing continues to be maintained.

Depending on the complexity of your applet, you may be able to rewrite it using [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX), the replacement for Swing. The libraries implementing JavaFX, OpenJFX, are not a required part of Java. You can add the libraries yourself or obtain a JDK that bundles them (ZuluFX or LibericaFX).

If you want to automatically deliver and launch your rewritten Java app through the convenience of a web browser, learn about the open-source re-implementation of [*Java Web Start*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) and [*Java Network Launching Protocol (JNLP)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start#Java_Network_Launching_Protocol_(JNLP)) technology known as [*OpenWebStart*](https://openwebstart.com/).

If you want to rebuild your applet as a web app written in pure Java, I suggest the [*Vaadin Flow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin#Vaadin_Flow_(Java_API)) framework.